# wrapping image inside a css grid with an anchor tag = top/bottom margins?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css grid that looks great without any anchor links attached to it.

However, whenever I wrap on of the images with a href anchor, it suddenly introduces a top and bottom margin/padding.

I have tried everything I could think off to get rid of that spacing, but nothing works.

What am I missing?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.grid-wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.grid-wrapper>div>a {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.grid-wrapper>div>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541845157-a6d2d100c931?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588282322673-c31965a75c3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588117472013-59bb13edafec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587588354456-ae376af71a25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src=" https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980663-3685c1d673c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1000&amp;q=60" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="tall"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588499756884-d72584d84df5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588492885706-b8917f06df77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588247866001-68fa8c438dd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=564&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586521995568-39abaa0c2311?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572914857229-37bf6ee8101c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="tall"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588453862014-cd1a9ad06a12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588414734732-660b07304ddb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588224575346-501f5880ef29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574798834926-b39501d8eda2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547234935-80c7145ec969?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1353&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588263823647-ce3546d42bfe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587732608058-5ccfedd3ea63?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587897773780-fe72528d5081?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588083949404-c4f1ed1323b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587572236558-a3751c6d42c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="wide"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583542225715-473a32c9b0ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="big"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527928159272-7d012024eb74?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553984840-b8cbc34f5215?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433446787703-42d5bf446876?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541187714594-731deadcd16a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540979388789-6cee28a1cdc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421930866250-aa0594cea05c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1355&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493306454986-c8877a09cbeb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1381&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536466528142-f752ae7bdd0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not apparent from your example.

Comment: That said I would always use `display:block` on the images, not `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a lot of useless code then make the link a flex container.

```css
.grid-wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.grid-wrapper > div > a {
  /* added */
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* */
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.grid-wrapper  img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541845157-a6d2d100c931?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588282322673-c31965a75c3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588117472013-59bb13edafec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587588354456-ae376af71a25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src=" https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980663-3685c1d673c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1000&amp;q=60" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="tall"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588499756884-d72584d84df5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588492885706-b8917f06df77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588247866001-68fa8c438dd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=564&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586521995568-39abaa0c2311?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572914857229-37bf6ee8101c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="tall"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588453862014-cd1a9ad06a12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588414734732-660b07304ddb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588224575346-501f5880ef29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574798834926-b39501d8eda2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547234935-80c7145ec969?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1353&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588263823647-ce3546d42bfe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587732608058-5ccfedd3ea63?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587897773780-fe72528d5081?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588083949404-c4f1ed1323b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587572236558-a3751c6d42c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="wide"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583542225715-473a32c9b0ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="big"> -->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527928159272-7d012024eb74?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553984840-b8cbc34f5215?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433446787703-42d5bf446876?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541187714594-731deadcd16a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540979388789-6cee28a1cdc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421930866250-aa0594cea05c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1355&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493306454986-c8877a09cbeb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1381&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536466528142-f752ae7bdd0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```